# move cursor in picturebox image be zoom in another picturebox same website. I want did it in c# application windows

Tags: c#

I have a PictureBox in winforms c#. I get the picture in the PictureBox from a SQL server.

When the PictureBox displays the image I want to zoom in it with hovering cursor

I can do it in c#?

Thanks for help me

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I do not no example.

Comment: How can I zoom on image in picturebox

Comment: Image is scan chart

Answer (score 0):

see this example, I guess it is exactly what you need...

http://www.cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-scrollable-and-zoomable-image-viewer-in-csharp-part-1

Comment: It was difficult. I do not understand.

Comment: I want image in picurebox be same photos in windows 10 or windows photo viewer in windows 7